# Добавление значения к столбцу в Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть датафрейм df со столбцом "Курс" в котором хранятся float-значения. Мне нужно умножить каждую ячейку этого столбца на 0,1% (по факту вычислить курс с комиссией), однако, я не понимаю как это реализовать.

Comment: df['Курс+комиссия']=df.Курс*1.1

Comment: Умножение на `1.1` - добавление 10%. Может быть `* 1.001` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
df['Курс+комиссия'] = df['Курс'] * 1.1
```

Comment: Умножение на `1.1` - добавление 10%. Может быть `* 1.001` ?